# Query MySQL for permissions in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site where a user can have multiple permissions (view, edit, delete, create). Each of these is stored as a tinyint(1) field in the database.

I'm looking for the best (quickest?) way to query MySQL to see if the user has the ability to see this page. Here is a snippet:

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($user);
$resultset = mysql_query("SELECT view FROM testbankAccess WHERE uid LIKE $user");
while($result = mysql_fetch_row($resultset)) {
    if($result[0]=='1') { return true; }
}
return false;
```

Comment: ...and what's the problem with it? Does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$resultset = mysql_query("SELECT view FROM testbankAccess WHERE uid=$user LIMIT 1");
$result = mysql_fetch_row($resultset)
if($result[0]==1) { return true; }
```

I suppose it cannot be faster (there's almost nothing happening here) as long as uid is a key in your table.

Answer (score 2):

First, it's probably faster comparing uid and $user using `=` in favor of `LIKE`.

Then, as you are only interested in the first result, you don't need to loop through them.

```
$result = mysql_fetch_row($resultset);
return $result[0] == 1;
```